# Why does ipad return invalid touch locations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I noticed a crash in our application, and traced it back to an interesting problem.

I have a UIVIew that is 320x480.  It overrides touchesEnded:withEvent: and checks the touch location to do some logic.

The interesting thing is that on ipad (only) we were receiving touch events with an X range from 0 to 320... **inclusive**.  That's the important bit.

**How does a view with 320 pixels across have a potential for 321 different touch locations**?  Is this a known bug?  Is there some reason for it?

To replicate this, run your iphone app on an ipad (in the compatibility emulator mode), touch down in a view and slide your finger off one side or the other.  You'll receive a touch event with an x value of 0 or 320.  You can do this for Y too.  I can't replicate this on an iphone.

Comment: By pixels, you really mean points, right? And they're really units of area. The leftmost one goes from 0 to 1. The next one goes from 1 to 2. The 320th one goes from 319 to 320. 0 is the left edge of the leftmost point. 320 is the right edge of the rightmost point. I believe the recorded precision of the touch location is greater than the resolution in points or even pixels.

Comment: Nope, was referring to pixels.  I don't believe this logic should be different on iPad vs iPhone regardless.

Comment: You do have a point about the difference between iPad vs. iPhone. I can only take your word for it that there is a difference since I don't have access to an iPhone.

Comment: I just tried out your scenario, and I got point values (not pixel values -- I think you need to refresh in your mind what the difference is -- locations are in points, not pixels) from 0.0 through 320.0 on the iPad. Interesting, in the iPhone simulator, I got values in the range 1.0 to 319.0 for the regular iPhone, and 0.5 to 319.5 for the 3.5 inch and 4 inch versions. But I think the simulator recognizes the edges for its own purposes (or maybe it's OSX) so doesn't accurately reflect behavior of an actual iPhone. The regular iPhone sim. has an image of the device - the others don't.

Comment: The pixel thing isn't relevant to the question.  I just said it in one place and it's accurate--the view I had was 320 pixels wide on both devices.  As for what you're seeing on the simulator; this question is over 2 years old now, and it's pretty likely that behavior has changed.  I think it's worth leaving around as a record in case someone comes across the bug, but I wouldn't expect to reproduce it in new iOS versions.

Comment: Oh, jeez. I didn't realize it was so old. I must have found it looking for something else. Sorry about reviving an old thread. I'll leave it alone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A touch on a capacitive touch display isn't physically a single pixel, more likely a fuzzy noisy blob with only a probable location and diameter.  So this could be a result of some post processing adjustments between the analog measurements and the event handler.

Or this could also just be a bug.   Go ahead and report it to Apple.

Comment: I mean yes, I understand that the physical hardware has to collect an abstract set of stimuli, and somehow interpret that as a pixel location.  But those details should be long gone by the time it reaches the abstraction layer we're concerned with.  Unless that mapping is well defined a "touch" is kinda meaningless.  And yeah you're right, I would report it, but I just stopped reporting stuff to apple because they just default ask you to write them a sample application regardless of the problem.  Wish I had that kinda time on my hands.